# Replacing corresponding characters in Strings (java)

Tags: java, string

The task was: Write static function operating on and returning `String`s

```
public static String tr(String s, String from, String to)
```

This method returns a `String` in which all characters from `s` that are present in `from` are replaced by the corresponding (in the same position) characters from `to`. For this to make sense, all characters in `from` must be different and `from` and `to` should be of the same length. For example, if `from` is "abc" and `to` is "XXY", then all occurrences of ’a’ and ’b’ should be replaced by ’X’ and ’c’ by ’Y’.

The results from

```java
System.out.println(tr("November 2016", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ"));

System.out.println(tr("abcXYZ","aZcX","||Cx"));
```

should be NOVEMBER 2016 and |bCxY|, respectively.

Here's my code. I can't even compile it properly. Could anyone please have a look and help me out please.

```
public static String tr(String s, String from, String to) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if s.charAt(i) == from.charAt(i) {
            s = s.replace(s.charAt(i), to.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Your for loop is a problem.  What happens when the length of "s" is greater than "from" or "to"?

Comment: @ChristianHur yes, have just worked it out thanks to Scary Wombat, I've been learning Java for a month and it's still a bit confusing to me, thank you for letting me know, however, good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need brackets for your if statement

```
if (s.charAt(i) == from.charAt(i))
```

**Note** have checked your logic

You logic should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

    int idexof = from.indexOf(s.charAt(i));
    if (idexof != -1) {
        s = s.replace(s.charAt(i), to.charAt(idexof));   
    }

}
return s;
```

Comment: Oh God, it's so late, have completely overlooked it. Thank you. Compiled it now properly but seems to be completely wrong, ended up with something like this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
 at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
 at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:709)
 at Task07.tr(Task07.java:22)
 at Task07.main(Task07.java:40)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It makes so much sense now, I can't upvote unfortunately due to low rep but will mark best answer in 2 min, when I'm able to. Thank you again.