# How can I Replace per character in java

Tags: java

I have this task to mask the contents of a .CSV file using Java. Done with masking other field but the problem is masking the data in the Primary Key column.
I tried using the code below but it doesn't work. How should I do it?

```
String str = src.replaceAll("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "QLBNAVHTROFSEJMIKWPYGDUCZX");
```

Comment: Please see [ask], and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: How did you mask the other field? Can you post a reproducible example? Can you tell us in what way it doesn't work? Do you get an exception? Does the output differ from your expectations? What were they (the output and the expected output)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I masked the other field randomly per character.
ch = (char) (s_rnd.nextInt(26) + 'A');

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the expected output for the Primary key should be traceable for example: Input: "Elliot
". Output "Sddpqw"

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366771/replacing-corresponding-characters-in-strings-java ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you *could* do this, but regular expressions are not the approach I would choose. I would build a map of character to character and then iterate the characters in a given string building the transposed output with the map (and don't forget digits and lowercase letters). Something like,

```
private static Map<Character, Character> MASK_MAP = new HashMap<>();
static {
    String inChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 
          outChars = "QLBNAVHTROFSEJMIKWPYGDUCZX";
    inChars += inChars.toLowerCase()   + "0123456789";
    outChars += outChars.toLowerCase() + "8652103749";
    for (int i = 0; i < inChars.length(); i++) {
        MASK_MAP.put(inChars.charAt(i), outChars.charAt(i));
    }
}
private static String maskKey(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(MASK_MAP.get(s.charAt(i)));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And then call

```
String out = maskKey(inputString);
```